# Local paths active and causing error to web app. after publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, publishing

We're trying to publish our little web app here.
I've done it several times in the past and it worked pretty well.
As the tags states, its a MVC ASP.Net project coded with VS2008.

Other interns worked on that project and we tried to re-publish again and we have this error:

> [IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
>   XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXRepository..ctor() in
>   E:\XXXXXX\YYYYYYY\ZZZZZZ\XXXXXXXRepository.vb:11
>   XXXXXXX.HomeController..ctor() in
>   E:\XXXXXXX\YYYYYY\ZZZZZZ\Controllers\HomeController.vb:10

Problem is, the path pointed here E:\XXXXXXX....*Controller or *Rep is located on the LOCAL machine where the dev. is made. It's as if something was hardcoded directly in our local machines in the Rep.VB and HomeController.VB. It should point in the path where we published the whole project wich is not E:\XXX\YYY\ZZZ

Anyone ever encountered this ?

Thanks alot guys
Have a nice day.

-Tom

Answer (score 1):

That is just information about where to search error in source files, so those paths have nothing to do with error appearance, they just for debugging purposes - if you will compile from your machine, they will change, but error will not dissapear. 
Error message indicates, that problem is, that code tries to access array element, which is not there (let's say array has 1 element and program tries to access second one).

Comment: So may be data is different. I sugest you to open source file, that is mentioned in error stack trace and check mentioned line (XXXXXRepository.vb, line 11) - usually such error is pretty obvious from looking at source, if it is not, add loging before that line, that you would see what is going on.

Comment: We found out, it was a problem with the IIS configs :-)